# Passing State from a form to the main application - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

Thanks in advance for the help.

I'm trying to create an app in React.  The workflow is the user sees a signup modal.  Where they add their name and email.

After submitting the form they are taken to the main screen where their name is displayed next to an avatar image in the top right corner.

I'm using React Router to the effect of something like this

```
var routes = (
    <Router history={createHistory()}>
        <Route path="/" component={NewUserForm}/>
        <Route path="/user/:userName" component={App}/>
    </Router>
)
```

My form component:

```
var NewUserForm = React.createClass({
    addNewUser: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var newUser = {
            name: this.refs.name.value,
            email: this.refs.email.value
        };
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
      <form className="new-user-form" ref="newUser" onSubmit={this.addNewUser}>
        <input type="text" ref="name" placeholder="Your Name"/>
        <input type="email" ref="email" placeholder="Your Email"/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
});
```

My app component:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      user: {} 
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="main-app-body">
        <Header user={this.state.user}></Header>
        <Sidebar></Sidebar>
      </div>
    )
  }

});
```

Ultimately, I want to pass along the users name and email to the header component so that it's displayed at the top.  How do I pass along the user object?  I know how to pass data along from parent to child components with props, but not with siblings.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I'd rename you `App` component to `Main`, then wrap a new `App` component around `Main` and `NewUserForm`. Your new `App` component can handle the state for it's children.

Comment: If you want to sibling components to share state, you need to have a parent component that handles the state. You can use a flux-style data store, which all components subscribe to changes.

Answer (score 0):

React is unidirectional, you can use store from architecture like flux or redux